# How to prevent Firefox/Chrome/etc from updating password in Password Manager?

Tags: browser, passwords

I have a page where the user updates their password through an AJAX api call. The user inputs their current password along with two copies of the new password.

After the form is submitted, the browser asks the user if they would like to update their stored password. For a successful password change, this is exactly what I want.

However, if the password change is *not* successful, because the current password provided was incorrect or the new password wasn't long enough, I *don't* want the user to be prompted.

I'm currently returning an HTTP status code of 422 (Unprocessible Entity) when the password fails to update, although changing this to 400 (Bad Request) or 401 (Unauthorized) doesn't seem to make a difference.

Does anyone know how the browser decides whether to update the stored password or not in this case?

Comment: FWIW, I'm in the same boat right now and it is driving me insane.